# Windows Defender's MsMpEng.exe Access lsass.exe

Tags: windows, siem

I detected an activity last week on our SIEM system. The MsMpEng.exe which belongs to Windows Defender access lsass.exe. I search it on the net for learn is it a normal acitivty or is it anormal then there is no information about it. Activity's event ID is 4656. Anyone can explain it for me? Why windows defender access lsass.exe. Is it normal or anormal activity?

Answer (score 0):

Event ID 4656 tells you that a handle was *requested*, not that it was actually opened, or that anything was done with the handle. If the event shows up as an audit success, that means the creation of a handle was granted. If it's an audit failure, that means that access was denied.

You need to dig further into the event details to better understand what was happening. Here's an example event log:

```
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
   Security ID:  NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
   Account Name:  SYSTEM
   Account Domain:  Some-Machine
   Logon ID:  0x1b001
Object:
   Object Server:  Security
   Object Type:  File
   Object Name:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe
   Handle ID:  0x42
Process Information:
   Process ID:  0x123
   Process Name:  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.12.3456.7-0\MsMpEng.exe
Access Request Information:
   Transaction ID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   Accesses:  READ_CONTROL
     SYNCHRONIZE
     ReadData (or ListDirectory)
     ReadEA
     ReadAttributes   Access Mask:  0x120089
   Privileges Used for Access Check: -
   Restricted SID Count: 0
```

If you just glance at this, you might think that Defender opened a handle to the lsass.exe process, when in fact all it did was open a read-only handle to the file.

If, instead, you saw something like this:

```
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
   Security ID:  Some-Machine\Bob
   Account Name:  Bob
   Account Domain:  Some-Machine
   Logon ID:  0x1b001
Object:
   Object Server:  Security
   Object Type:  Process
   Object Name:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe
   Process ID:  0x456
   Handle ID:  0x42
Process Information:
   Process ID:  0x123
   Process Name:  C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\MsMpEng.exe
Access Request Information:
   Transaction ID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   Accesses:  READ_CONTROL
     SYNCHRONIZE
     ReadData (or ListDirectory)
     ReadEA
     ReadAttributes   Access Mask:  0x120089
   Privileges Used for Access Check: -
   Restricted SID Count: 0
```

You would see that the process requesting the access was not the real MsMpEng.exe, but something in the user's AppData directory.

Or, you might see this:

```
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
   Security ID:  NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
   Account Name:  SYSTEM
   Account Domain:  Some-Machine
   Logon ID:  0x1b001
Object:
   Object Server:  Security
   Object Type:  File
   Object Name:  C:\Users\Alice\Downloads\lsass.exe
   Handle ID:  0x42
Process Information:
   Process ID:  0x123
   Process Name:  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.12.3456.7-0\MsMpEng.exe
Access Request Information:
   Transaction ID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   Accesses:  READ_CONTROL
     SYNCHRONIZE
     ReadData (or ListDirectory)
     ReadEA
     ReadAttributes   Access Mask:  0x120089
   Privileges Used for Access Check: -
   Restricted SID Count: 0
```

This would indicate that the "lsass.exe" being accessed was actually in a user's downloads directory, and was not the legitimate Windows executable.

As for why Windows Defender would try to scan lsass.exe - scanning the file is certainly normal, and it's reasonable to expect that it might scan the real lsass.exe process too, in certain circumstances, or just open a handle to lsass.exe for any other number of reasons.

An access event *could* be an indication of something malicious going on, but it's more likely that it wasn't, and just the event ID alone doesn't tell you anything.